# Change exit code from 0 to 1 in bash script

Tags: bash, variable

I have a script that rsyncs and ends like this

```
rsync -azvh /dir -e ssh usr@server.com:/
RESULT="$?"

# check result of rsync db's
if [ "$RESULT" != "0" ]; then
    echo -e "rsync exit Code:" $RESULT "\nFAILED to rsync backups"
else
    echo "SUCCESSFULL rsync of backups"
fi
```

I have just been asked to wrap it in an API but the API states that `0=fail` and `1=success`. How can I change the exit code to reflect this? Do I need to assign it a variable?

Comment: “0=fail and 1=success”!! That's very bad. The rest of the world uses 0=success and 1–255=fail for exit statuses. Doing the opposite is incompatible with shell logical operators, with `set -e`, with make, ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`exit 1` will exit with an error code of 1 and `exit 0` will exit with an error code of 0.

For instance:

```
rsync -azvh /dir -e ssh usr@server.com:/
RESULT="$?"

# check result of rsync db's
if [ "$RESULT" != "0" ]; then
    echo -e "rsync exit Code:" $RESULT "\nFAILED to rsync backups"
    exit 0
else
    echo "SUCCESSFULL rsync of backups"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Revised answer, report `false` (or `(exit 1)`), and `true`
   as needed as per non-standard API:

   ```
   rsync -azvh /dir -e ssh usr@server.com:/
   RESULT="$?"
   # check result of rsync db's
   if [ "$RESULT" = "0" ]; then
       echo "SUCCESSFULL rsync of backups"
       false
   else
       echo -e "rsync exit Code:" $RESULT "\nFAILED to rsync backups"
       true
   fi
   ```
2. If all that text output isn't really needed, the code could be much
   reduced:

   ```
   ! rsync -azvh /dir -e ssh usr@server.com:/
   ```

   ...all that's needed is to precede `rsync` with a logical NOT `!` 
   and return the opposite of what `rsync` returns.

Answer (score 0):

super easy via bash:

```
test $((`echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" | tr ' ' '+'`)) -eq 0
echo $?
```